# Ruby on Rails - Creating a form for a collection of objects that have no parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Under more typical circumstances (ie the objects being edited/created belong to another model) the following would work:

models

```
Person < AR:Base
  has_many :things
end

Thing < AR:Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

haml

```
=form_for @person do |f|
  =f.fields_for :things do |thing_form|
   =thing_form.description
```

However I need to edit a collection of things (queried from the database .. select * from things where created_at > 2012-01-01) without consideration for the Person they belong to (some don't even belong to a person).

My fields_for /should/ look something like this, but I'm not sure how to set it up before this (as I have no object to build the form from)

```
...
-@things.each do |thing|
  =f.fields_for :thing, thing do |thing_fields|
    =thing_form.description
```

if I could make a 'dummy' person and load the things array with my selection of things, then save it Person without actually saving the dummy, that would work... but how? :)

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem for categories of user. See my solution below.

```
- Category.all.each do |c|
    = check_box_tag "user[category_ids][]", c.id, @user.categories.include?(c), :id => "user_category_ids_#{c.id}"
```

Comment: how do you handle saving/updating the collection?

Comment: attr_accessible "category_ids" in model and @user.update_attributes params[:user] in controller